# How to cast a member variable of class in C++

Tags: c++, json, class, casting, attributes

I have defined a class  `JsonElement` in that way :

```
class JsonElement {
public:
    string key;
    void* value;
    template<typename T>
    void setValue(T val){
        static_cast<T>(value);
        this->value=val;
    }
};
```

My question is simple :
How can I cast the value of `value` to any primitive type?

I don't want to use  this solution :

```
template<typename T>
class JsonElement {
public:
    string key;
    T value;
};
```

because I don't know yet the type of `value` the moment I create the object.

Any help, please?

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags (like the C language tag to your C++ question). But also please include relevant tags (like JSON).

Comment: Side note on terminology: attributes are meta information for the compiler. What you call an attribute is called a field or member variable in C++ land.

Comment: As for your problem, you can't just cast, you need to do explicit conversion. For JSON I recommend you store all values as *strings* and then use e.g. `std::ostringstream` to extract and "convert" the string into the type you want.

Comment: And on a related note, all JSON values can be *other* JSON object, or lists. So a plain string isn't really enough either.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant might help out in this situation?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, this is the simplest element that we can find in JSON file, I know there are others. My point here is to find a solution to cast a member variable.

Comment: @BasGroothedde, I am using c++98.

Comment: why are you using C++98?

Comment: @Timo, i am working in an old embedded environment.

Comment: ouch. That environment is almost older than I am.

Comment: @Timo, I don't know if I can change the compiler?

Comment: well I'd try upgrading if possible, but you have to figure that out on your own. I'm not an embedded dev so I don't know how difficult that would be.

Comment: Basically, you need `std::variant` or something substantially similar. If you can't use one in the standard library, you'd have to find third-party implementation or roll your own. See if you could get [boost::variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/variant.html) work with your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this would never work:

```
    void setValue(T val){
        static_cast<T>(value);
        this->value=val;
    }
```

`static_cast` casts at compile time, and will not cast as there is no relation between any object and a `void*` (normally). You need a C-style cast (like I am doing here, but feel free to use a ) or a `reinterpret_cast` to do this.

Fixed:

```
class JsonElement {
public:
    string key;
    void* value;

    template<typename T>
    void setValue(T val) {
        value = (void*)val; //cast our value to a void*, and store it
    }

    template<typename T>
    T getValue() {
        return (T)value; //cast our void* to our value, and return it
    } 
};
```

I tested this with this small program:

```
int main() {
    JsonElement j;
    j.setValue<int>(5);
    int i = j.getValue<int>();
    std::cout << i;
}
```

It prints 5 as expected.